# Why pulse of light spread as time goes by?

Tags: visible-light, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, redshift

I read in the [*A Brief History of Time* by Stephen Hawking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time) that as time goes by, a pulse of light spreads out. In the book he says:

> As we have seen, Maxwell's equations predicted that the speed of light should be the same whatever the speed of the source, and this has been confirmed by accurate measurements. It follows from this that if a pulse of light is emitted at a particular time at a particular point in space, then as time goes on it will spread out as a sphere of light whose size and position are independent of the speed of the source. After one millionth of a second the light will have spread out to form a sphere with a radius of 300 meters; after two millionths of a second, the radius will be 600 meters; and so on.

I didn't understand it. Can someone explain what the paragraph means?

Comment: Assuming you mean [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Theory-Everything-Origin-Fate-Universe/dp/8179925919) I can't see where in the book it discusses a pulse of light spreading out. Can you give us the chapter and preferably page number in the book where this is discussed?

Comment: no, sorry, I wrote wrong book name. It's in the brief history of time, on page no. 28, last paragraph, chapter 2.

Comment: Do you mean the line *It follows from this that if a pulse of light is emitted at a particular time at a particular point in space, then as time goes on it will spread out as a sphere of light whose size and position are independent of the speed of the source.*

Comment: yes, John Rennie, that's the line I asked about.

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: Edit your question more clear, quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to John Rennie, we now know the full quote is

> It follows from this that if a pulse of light is emitted at a particular time at a particular point in space, then as time goes on it will spread out as a sphere of light whose size and position are independent of the speed of the source.

This is simply saying that if you have a short flash of light at one point, emitting light in all directions, then

1. The light will keep traveling in all directions
2. Because the pulse is short, you can think of all the light as being in a "soap bubble" (thin shell) that is some distance from where it was emitted
3. That sphere will grow with time (because $x = vt$, or in this case $r = ct$, the radius is the product of the speed of light, and the time since the flash)
4. Light speed is constant in all directions, regardless of the speed of the source: this is why it's always a sphere

Maybe this picture helps:

[image]

The red dot in the middle is the source of the light; regardless of whether it is stationary (left) or moving (right), the envelope of the light pulse will travel in all directions at the same speed.

Does that clear it up?